# (node:23840) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: javascript, node.js, vite

I was installing some dependencies using npm install and then, while it was getting installed I kept on getting the following warning:

```
PS D:\EXTRA CLASSES\Web Development\React\react-course-v3-main\04-fundamental-projects\02-tours\starter> npm install
(node:23840) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:23840) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:23840) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:23840) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:23840) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:23840) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
[..................] / idealTree:starter: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

I tried doing the following as suggested in the error message:

```
PS D:\EXTRA CLASSES\Web Development\React\react-course-v3-main\04-fundamental-projects\02-tours\starter> emitter.setMaxListeners(0)
```

but then it gave the following error:

```
emitter.setMaxListeners : The term 'emitter.setMaxListeners' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

What can I do to fix this issue?